# Django Template: Add Variable Into URL As Parameter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, querystringparameter

What's the proper way to add `{{gamestoday|lookup:i}}` into the `<a href={%url 'stats'%}>`. Do I need to make changes to urls.py?

```
{% load tags %}
<center>
<div class = "scoreboardbackground">
    <div class="row">
{% for i in ngames %}
    <div class="col">

        
        <a href={%url 'stats'%}>
        <div class="livegamebox">
            {{teamnames|lookup:i|lookup:0}} vs {{teamnames|lookup:i|lookup:1}} - {{gamestoday|lookup:i}}
        
            <br>

            <div style="font-size:12px;">
            {{datetimegames|lookup:i}}
            </div> 
        
            <br>

            <div style = "font-size:30px">
            <b>{{latestscore|lookup:i}}</b>
            </div>
        </div>

        </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found quite an easy solve, syntax-related:

Modified the template's anchor element like this - `<a href={%url 'stats' %}?game={{gamestoday|lookup:i}}>`

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass variables as parameters:

Having:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<str:username>/', views.user_profile, name='user_profile')
]
```

You can:

```html
 <a href={% url 'user_profile' username=username %}>
```

Comment: still not clear. in my example `{{gamestoday|lookup:i}}` gamestoday is just a list passed from the homeView with lookup being a custom tag used for getting the value on position i from the list. since all the data comes from an api, I am not planning on storing it in my own db.

Comment: you can than use the django default tag `{% with param=gamestoday|lookup:i   %}` and pass `param` into the url. Remember to close with `{% endwith %}`.