# Add template variable into URL and satisfy reverse match

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I found a way to inject variables into the URL per [Django Template: Add Variable Into URL As Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201684/django-template-add-variable-into-url-as-parameter), but my reverse match is not working. Do I need to use re-path and use regular expressions?

Current url.py

```
    path('student/item/drilldown/<str:type>/<int:num>/',views.StudentBehaviorListView.as_view(),name='student_item_list_drilldown'),
```

Original w/hard-coding:

```
<a href="{%url 'registration:student_item_list_drilldown' type='grade' num=6%}">
```

With variable injection:

```
<a href="{%url 'registration:student_item_list_drilldown'%}?type=grade&num={{i.grade}}">{{i.grade}}th Grade</a>
```

Error message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /registration/dashboard/
Reverse for 'student_item_list_drilldown' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['registration/student/item/drilldown/(?P<type>[^/]+)/(?P<num>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
{% url 'registration:student_item_list_drilldown' %}
```

Will try to find path named `student_item_list_drilldown` before it is read as html. That's why it tries (and fails) to find `<str:type>` and `<int:num>` in `{% url 'registration:student_item_list_drilldown' %}`. You have to include that variables inside `{% url ... %}` brackets.

The best approach would be that:

```
{% url 'registration:student_item_list_drilldown' 'grade' i.grade %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you suggest how I add in the i.grade variable in here?

Comment: I've edited. `{% url 'registration:student_item_list_drilldown' 'grade' i.grade %}` should work like a charm :)